# expressing class of inversions in einstein summation convention

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, tensors, inversive-geometry

I'm working on a personal project where I'm studying the set of [inversions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry) in $\Bbb R^n$
that preserve the unit sphere centered at the origin; these transformations can be defined based on a center of inversion $c$, like so:

$$I_{c}(x) = (c\cdot c-1){{x-c}\over{(x-c)\cdot(x-c)}}+c$$

I'm curious about how this would be expressed in Einstein summation convention, but I'm not too familiar with it and my attempts have failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be$$[I_c(x)]_i=\frac{c_jc_j-1}{(x_k-c_k)(x_k-c_k)}(x_i-c_i)+c_i.$$

Comment: this assumes orthonormal basis vectors, right?

Comment: @sortai I suppose if you wanted another basis some matrix $M$ would exist for which $u\cdot v=u_jM_{jk}v_k$.